# Windows 10 - no boot, reset PC fails, dism fails

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, dism

My Windows 10 PC recently stopped booting (black screen, spinner rotates forever...). I tried a bunch of ideas (startup repair - fails, boot from USB key and repair - fails, reset my PC - fails).

Ran dism which found 23 corrupt files. In the absence of any relevant help / available old images from Microsoft tech support, I found a Windows 10 build (17763.379) on [this site](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php) to use as source for the dism /restorehealth call but it appears that the files on the source do not match the files on my system:

```
2020-06-14 10:36:14, Info                  CSI    00000009 Hashes for file member [l:11]'msvcm90.dll' do not match.
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to download a specific build of Windows 10 (for me, that appears to be 10.0.17763.1)? Or even a way to reset the PC which seems to be restricted at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can download latest Windows ISO from [windows 10 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) using a Linux computer or if from a Windows computer then in Firefox go to

```
about:config
```

and change/add "general.useragent.override" to "Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.2.2; Tablet; rv:47.0) Gecko/47.0 Firefox/47.0" then if you try to access the above link you can download the needed ISO. Just take care to select the correct Home or Pro edition, bitness doesn't matter.

To put the ISO on an USB stick use rufus or follow this link:
[install windows from an USB flash drive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/install-windows-from-a-usb-flash-drive)

**Edit**: see Akeo's info and [link](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Help_I_dont_see_the_ISO_download_button): you can do the whole process from rufus (not only the USB creation but also the ISO download).

Comment: You know Rufus __can__ download the Windows 10 ISOs straight from Microsoft's servers and that there's no need to use the `User-Agent` trick, right? https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Help_I_dont_see_the_ISO_download_button